# How to safely access Network in a thread pool?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have the following code which is used to access the network using a thread pool(aka, **the following code might be called by several different threads at the same time**.)

```
                ...
                QEventLoop q;
                QNetworkReply *reply;
                QNetworkRequest qheader;
                QNetworkAccessManager network;
                QTimer tT;
                tT.setSingleShot(true);
                connect(&network, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
                        &q, SLOT(quit()));
                connect(&tT, SIGNAL(timeout()), &q, SLOT(quit()));
                network.setProxy(Proxy);


                QString url=MakeImageUrl(type,pos,zoom,LanguageStr);
                qheader.setUrl(QUrl(url));
                qheader.setRawHeader("User-Agent",UserAgent);
                qheader.setRawHeader("Accept","*/*");

                reply=network.get(qheader);
                ret=reply->readAll();
                reply->deleteLater();
                ...
```

Then the program some times crash at the `reply = network.get(qheader)`, am I doing anything wrong here? I have tried qt5.4.1 and qt4.8.6, though the callstack of the crash is not exactly the same, I just wonder how correct is the above code?

Comment: are you sure you're not calling something static, like into MakeImageUrl or from the UserAgent variable that may get corrupted ? Try to remove any call inside external function and keep the objects sealed...

Comment: Will that cause a problem? I am still looking into the code.

Comment: if you call it from multiple threads, and you do not protect what's inside those functions yes, it may cause a crash because the return value, maybe into the url QString may be corrupted.